# ./components/Avatar.tsx Error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-stage-0'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs, next.js

After a few hours of research, I still haven't solved an issue I've been having with Babel and Webpack. ): I'm sure the solution is simple.

My .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-stage-0"]
}
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "sabrinasbase",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chokidar": "^3.5.1",
    "css-modules-typescript-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "next": "10.0.5",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-particles-js": "^3.4.1",
    "react-tsparticles": "^1.18.11",
    "sass": "^1.32.5",
    "three": "^0.124.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-stage-0": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/register": "^7.12.10",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.22",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.16.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.4.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.2.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10"
  }
}
```

My webpack.config.js

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  //mode: "production",
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  context: path.join(__dirname, "pages"),

  entry: ["/_app.js" /*main*/],
  output: {
    filename: "./bundle.js", // in /dist
  },
  resolve: {
    // Add `.ts` and `.tsx` as a resolvable extension.
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".css", ".scss"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" },

      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" }, // to inject the result into the DOM as a style block
          { loader: "css-modules-typescript-loader" }, // to generate a .d.ts module next to the .scss file (also requires a declaration.d.ts with "declare modules '*.scss';" in it to tell TypeScript that "import styles from './styles.scss';" means to load the module "./styles.scss.d.td")
          { loader: "css-loader", options: { modules: true } }, // to convert the resulting CSS to Javascript to be bundled (modules:true to rename CSS classes in output to cryptic identifiers, except if wrapped in a :global(...) pseudo class)
          { loader: "sass-loader" }, // to convert SASS to CSS
          // NOTE: The first build after adding/removing/renaming CSS classes fails, since the newly generated .d.ts typescript module is picked up only later
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.png|jpg|gif$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "url-loader",
            options: {
              limit: 8192,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      { test: /\.js|tsx|ts$/, loader: "babel-loader", exclude: /node_modules/ },
    ],
  },
};
```

All I want to do is import a picture into a component. Originally I was getting `Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions` error, but now I am getting vaguer errors that the module isn't working correctly. There were a few times that the Webpack would compile successfully, but the file I wanted to use wouldn't. Is there anything I am missing? I promise I am installing the preset-stage-0 package.

```
Error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-stage-0'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Sabri\Documents\GitHub\sabrinasbase\sabrinasbase\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\babel\bundle.js
- C:\Users\Sabri\Documents\GitHub\sabrinasbase\sabrinasbase\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\babel\code-frame.js
- C:\Users\Sabri\Documents\GitHub\sabrinasbase\sabrinasbase\node_modules\next\dist\lib\typescript\diagnosticFormatter.js
- C:\Users\Sabri\Documents\GitHub\sabrinasbase\sabrinasbase\node_modules\next\dist\lib\typescript\runTypeCheck.js
- C:\Users\Sabri\Documents\GitHub\sabrinasbase\sabrinasbase\node_modules\next\dist\lib\verifyTypeScriptSetup.js
- C:\Users\Sabri\Documents\GitHub\sabrinasbase\sabrinasbase\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-dev-server.js
- C:\Users\Sabri\Documents\GitHub\sabrinasbase\sabrinasbase\node_modules\next\dist\server\next.js
- C:\Users\Sabri\Documents\GitHub\sabrinasbase\sabrinasbase\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js
- C:\Users\Sabri\Documents\GitHub\sabrinasbase\sabrinasbase\node_modules\next\dist\cli\next-dev.js
- C:\Users\Sabri\Documents\GitHub\sabrinasbase\sabrinasbase\node_modules\next\dist\bin\next
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at loadFileChain.next (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: Hi share the current error please

Comment: Also I just found out that "As of v7.0.0-beta.55, we've removed Babel's Stage presets."

Comment: Added the error above. I noticed that as well, but I'm not sure what the alternative solution is..

Comment: This may help?
https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/755ec192e22c6b6e00782e4810366d0166fdbebd/packages/babel-preset-stage-0/README.md

Comment: could be version mismatch of react vs babel, I faced similar issues when babel 7 was released, not very sure though, posted my optimized webpack below, done compression and css reduction apart from standard optimization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are getting this error

Here is my webpack which works as expected
Also, apologies in advance as I have done heck load of optimization to reduce bundle size

Webpack.config.base.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const ServiceWorkerWebpackPlugin = require('serviceworker-webpack-plugin');
const {WebpackManifestPlugin} = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const ESLintPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin');
const PurifyCssPlugin = require('purifycss-webpack');
const glob = require("glob");


module.exports = {
    target: 'web',
    stats: 'verbose',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: '[name].[hash].bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "html-loader"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    options: {
                        publicPath: './'
                    }
                }, 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    options: {
                        publicPath: './'
                    }
                }, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    'file-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
                        options: {
                            bypassOnDebug: true, // webpack@1.x
                            disable: true, // webpack@2.x and newer
                            mozjpeg: {
                                progressive: true,
                            },
                            optipng: {
                                enabled: false,
                            },
                            pngquant: {
                                quality: [0.65, 0.90],
                                speed: 4
                            },
                            gifsicle: {
                                interlaced: false,
                            },
                        },
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [
                {from: "icons", to: "icons"},
                {from: "./manifest.webmanifest", to: ""},
                {from: "./.htaccess", to: ""},
                {from: "./robots.txt", to: ""}
            ],
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name].[hash].css"

        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./src/app/index.html",
            favicon: "./src/assets/image/favicon.png",
            inject: true,
            minify: {
                removeComments: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true
            }
        }),
        new ServiceWorkerWebpackPlugin({
            entry: path.join(__dirname, './src/app/serviceWorker/serviceWorkerInit.js'),
        }),
        new WebpackManifestPlugin({
            fileName: 'asset-manifest.json', // Not to confuse with manifest.json
        }),
        new ESLintPlugin({files: './src/app/app.js'}),
        new PurifyCssPlugin({
            paths: [
                ...(glob.sync(`./src/app/*.html`)),
                ...(glob.sync(`./src/app/**/*.jsx`)),
                ...(glob.sync(`./dist/*.html`))
            ],
            styleExtensions: ['.css','.scss'],
            moduleExtensions: [".html"],
            verbose: true,
            purifyOptions: {
                info: true,
                minify: true,
                whitelist: ["*purify*"]
            },
        })
    ]
};
```

Webpack.config.prod.js

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');
const webpackBaseConfiguration = require('./webpack.config.base.js');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin')
const webpack = require('webpack');


const GLOBALS = {
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
    __DEV__: false
};


module.exports = merge(webpackBaseConfiguration,{
    mode: 'production',
    entry: [
        '@babel/polyfill',
        './src/app/app.jsx'
    ],
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist'
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all',
            minSize: 20000,
            maxSize: 0,
            minChunks: 2,
            maxAsyncRequests: 30,
            maxInitialRequests: 30,
            enforceSizeThreshold: 50000,
            cacheGroups: {
                defaultVendors: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    priority: -10,
                    reuseExistingChunk: true
                },
                default: {
                    minChunks: 2,
                    priority: -20,
                    reuseExistingChunk: true
                }
            }
        },
        usedExports: true,
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                parallel: true,
                terserOptions: {
                    ecma: 6,
                },
            }),
            new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin()
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
       new webpack.DefinePlugin(GLOBALS),
        new CompressionPlugin({
            algorithm: 'gzip',
            minRatio: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
        }),
        new CompressionPlugin({
            filename: "[path].br",
            algorithm: "brotliCompress",
            test: /\.(js|css|html|svg|png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
            deleteOriginalAssets: false,
            minRatio: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
        })
    ]
});
```

Webpack.config.dev.js

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const webpackBaseConfiguration = require('./webpack.config.base');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = merge(webpackBaseConfiguration,{
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './src',
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    entry: [
        '@babel/polyfill',
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
        './src/app/app.jsx'
    ],
    plugins: [
        /*For hot deployment*/
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ]
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Sample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "React app",
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "deploy": "node deploy",
    "build:prod:deploy": "npm run clean && webpack --mode production --config webpack.config.prod.js && node deploy",
    "build:prod": "npm run clean && webpack --mode production --config webpack.config.prod.js",
    "build:dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --config webpack.config.dev.js --open --hot",
    "start": "npm run build && npm run deploy",
    "build": "npm run clean && webpack --mode production --config webpack.config.prod.js && npm run deploy"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x",
    "npm": "6.x"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/node": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.3.0",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.2.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "@gfx/zopfli": "^1.0.15",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "brotli-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "6.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.18.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^2.4.1",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "ftp-deploy": "^2.4.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.6",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "image-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "imagemin-gifsicle": "^7.0.0",
    "imagemin-jpegtran": "^7.0.0",
    "imagemin-optipng": "^8.0.0",
    "imagemin-svgo": "^8.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.5.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.1",
    "purify-css": "^1.2.5",
    "purifycss-webpack": "^0.7.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.3",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "serviceworker-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "4.2.3",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.1",
    "webpack": "^4.40.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.5.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-ftp-upload-plugin": "^1.0.3",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.24.3",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.1",
    "workbox-cacheable-response": "^6.0.2",
    "workbox-expiration": "^6.0.2",
    "workbox-routing": "^6.0.2",
    "workbox-strategies": "^6.0.2",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.2",
    "zlib": "^1.0.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "react": "^16.8.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.1",
    "react-lazy-load-image-component": "^1.5.1",
    "react-paginate": "^6.5.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "^2.1.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Again Apologies from my side as the webpack might look messy due to so many plugins for optimization, this app had PWA integrated so needed to reduce the app size

Comment: Also I see you havent given "@babel/polyfill" in entry, try that, could help

Comment: Okay, I decided to ditch Babel for now as I don't need it for the purpose I wanted to use it for anyway. I ended up coming across even more errors regarding Webpack, so it must have been a deeply embedded problem of some other means.  I am appreciative for your attempt to help me though. Have a good day. @VikasSaini